# How do I create a program that will click on certain x/y coordinates on the screen when a hotkey is pressed? JAVA/Windows 7

Tags: button, mouse, click, location, coordinate

In Java, I'm trying to force rapid mouse clicks on certain x/y locations on my computer by pressing a certain hotkey, I know how to assign the hotkey the actions to do things but I don't know what the method is for the x/y clicks. There are no buttons on those locations to fire off so it's just clicking on set locations. Please help :) Thank you

I'm working with java and running Windows 7.

Comment: well, it would be more than interesting which environment and which language you prefer

Answer (score 0):

How about calling the click-event handler directly from the hotkey-event handler with the right coordinates?

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought, but I can't seem to get it to work and It's upsetting me. :(